# How to make the Sql query efficent

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am running a sql query on about 2.5 million data but it computes the answer extremely slow.Is there any way to make a query compute the particular answer fast.

My query is

```
SELECT COUNT(FarmerName) AS Total_Number_Of_Farmers 
FROM try  
WHERE FarmerName <> '-'"
```

Comment: show us your through out task so that we can think a little abt it

Comment: Do you have an index on `FarmerName`?

Comment: The only way to speed this up would be to add a specific Index to the `FarmerName` column.

Comment: I didnt do any indexing..How to do that?

Comment: @user1056466 Check here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Comment: Because the operator is `<>`, an index is unlikely to be used on FarmerName. If the operator was `=` then it might be used.

Comment: @ElectricLlama it may help in the case SQL Server convert internally to find all the records which equal '-' and then do the minus from total records in the table, your thoughts. Getting the total count from a table will be very qucik

Comment: I'm not sure how to include your restriction with the data in this blog post, but it has some alternative ways to write the query: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx

Comment: @ElectricLlama Devesh is correct, the reason to put an index on FarmerName is to leverage the COUNT, which would be much faster if there was a specific index.

Comment: The fact that `FarmerName` is inside the `COUNT` function is irrelevant. `COUNT(DISTINCT FarmerName)` on the other hand _might_ use an index on `FarmerName` but you'd have to test to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try index on 'FarmerName'

```
CREATE INDEX FarmerNameIndex
ON try (Farmername)
```

Also, If this field is `NVarchar` either change it to `varchar`, or use `WHERE FarmerName <> N'-'"`

Comment: The cost of transcoding a tiny string literal should be infinitesimal.  The index would be a really good idea, though.

Comment: query will remain same.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what does nvarchar vs. varchar have to do with using a filtered index? Shouldn't you be using that anyway if you're always going to use the same filter in the SELECT query? I mean other than if the data in the column itself takes too much space.

Comment: Mr.Tilak which just using the above query it will automatically create index...or i have to do more.

Comment: `Create Index ...` will create the index, then re run the query. @kahn, idea is to reduce/remove the implicit conversion, by making both sides of type same (ie if field is varchar, match with varchar, and if field is nvarchar, match with nvarchar)

Comment: when do i execute the index query ? while creating the table or running the query normally ? after the index is created is the index permanent ?

Comment: Tilak: ah of course, thanks. :D @user1056466: Indexes are permanent and will be used automatically when applicable. After the creation you should see a considerable boost in efficiency. You can also check whether it's used by including the execution plan with SQL Server (basic shortcut is CTRL + M in the query window).

Comment: it is automatically called. It remains permanently until removed using `Drop Index`

Comment: @Tilak Following error occured Column 'FarmerName' in table 'try' is of type that is invalid for use as a key column  in an index.FarmerName column is varchar(max) how will i do indexing on it..I am new to indexing please help.

Comment: You cant have index on `varchar(max)`. (These fields can be part of multi field index though). You should change it to something like `varchar(100)` or `varchar(200)`, depending upon your maximum anticipated data type.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Make use of Query Execution Plan option in SSMS. This will suggest you with missed index. Although the suggested missed index is not always trustworthy, by looking at the execution plan you can easily figure out on which column you need to create an index. Try to reduce Index Scans and Table Scans as much as possible. Convert them to Index seek wherever possible. This will improve the performance a lot.

For your query, as @ElectricLlama suggested, applying '<>' would have extra burden. It is always better to use '=', so that it can make use of index on that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
create INDEX FarmerNameIndex
ON try (Farmername)
```

then execute the same query as you have written above.

```
 select COUNT(FarmerName) Total_Number_Of_Farmers 
 FROM try  
 where FarmerName <> '-'"
```

Note: try to set the datatype as small as require for father name.